# Right way to accommodate an HTTP GET that could "skip" to a POST?

Tags: http

Let's say you have a HTTP GET request which could be skipped in some circumstances. For example, imagine you have:

- `GET /orders/new`, which lets you pick what flavor of ice cream you want
- `POST /orders`, which makes a new ice cream order

Normally, `GET /orders/new` shows you the list of flavors and a Submit button. But if there's only one flavor available today, you'd like to just `POST` the order to avoid having the user make a useless decision. (We'll imagine this is a universe in which everyone likes all flavors equally and so will always be happy with your dictatorial ice cream choice.)

It doesn't seem correct to do something like "redirect to POST" from a GET request, since that wouldn't be idempotent. So then what's the right way to do this:

- if there's more than one flavor: let the user pick the flavor(s) they want for their order
- if there's only one flavor: pick the only flavor for their order and immediately make the order
- either way, wind up with a newly `POST`ed order

Answer (score 0):

It's a `GET`, it should *never* result in a `POST`. Period. If you want to avoid the choice, avoid doing the `GET` entirely somewhere in the flow *before* the `GET /orders/new`. Maybe I only want to see the flavors, but not actually proceed with an order.